# QQuickImageProvider for animated images

Tags: image, qt5, gif, qtquick2, animated-gif

Does anyone know if there is way to provide a animated image to `AnimatedImage` without using a `url`? The thing is, that I get a base64 encoded GIF via HTTPS that I want to display with the help of `AnimatedImage`. I thought about using `QQuickImageProvider`, but unfortunately `QQuickImageProvider` cannot be used with `AnimatedImage`but only with `Image`. (see also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30524 ).

Can anyone think of another way to accomplish this? The only thing I can think of, is actually writing the file to the disk and using the `url` parameter (which is really inefficent).

Comment: Maybe go one layer below, and provide your custom `QNetworkAccessManager` in the `QQmlEngine` that performs the base64->`image/gif` conversion?

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late response! I can't follow your idea completely. I already have a custom `QNetworkAccessManager` that fetches the picture from the server. But unfortunately I am not able to feed the `AnimatedImage` with the byte string. I also thought about letting the `source` parameter point to a Web URL to let the `AnimatedImage` handle the  fetching and displaying. But I think that approach doesn't scale when the `AnimatedImage` is used in a newsfeed like application.

Comment: Why do you think that your network access manager will do a better job than the default one used by Qt Quick? The url handling in Qt Quick is done asynchronously from a separate thread, when the data is ready, the `AnimatedImage` receives the movie and starts displaying it. Have you actually tried it out? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You are right, I could set a url in `AnimatedImage` to let the `AnimatedImage` handle the loading asynchronously. However, as the `AnimatedImage` will be used in a delegate inside a `ListView` I think it's smoother to load the GIF data before and then use the data in memory as source. (e.q my application sends a request to get 20 base64 encoded GIFs. After the data is received, I want to populate the `ListView`s model with the base64 encoded GIF. And the `AnimatedImage` should use that data as `source`